# Add new column in pandas df on basis str contains and equals

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, data-science

I want to add new column on basis of if column Local Channel Name contains HFS than new column value is MM and if Column Contains MR than value should be MR and if nothing matched it will be Small

Here is the dataframe

```
    Site            Month               Local Channel Name                       Total
    Ahmedabad   FEBRUARY 2022   LARGE A PHARMACY [2002813449] HFS       2
    Ahmedabad   FEBRUARY 2022   LARGE A PHARMACY [2002813449]           7
    Ahmedabad   FEBRUARY 2022   LARGE A PHARMACY 
    Ahmedabad   FEBRUARY 2022   LARGE A PHARMACY [2002813449]   MR      1
    Ahmedabad   FEBRUARY 2022   LARGE B PHARMACY                        4
```

The actual logic which I am trying to code in pandas is
[image: logic-part1]
[image: logic-part2]

I have tried this

```
df1['Channel Group'] = pd.np.where(df1['Local Channel Name'].str.contains(regex1),"ECOM",
pd.np.where( df1['Cust Type Name'].str.contains(regex),"MR",
pd.np.where(df1['Cust Type Name'].str.match(regex5),"HFS MM",     
pd.np.where(df1['Local Channel Name'].str.match(regex2),"HFS MM", 
pd.np.where(df1['Cust Type Name'].str.match(regex3),"HFS MM",  
pd.np.where(df1['Cust Type Name'].str.match(regex6),"HFS MM",
pd.np.where(df1['Local Channel Name'].str.contains(regex4),"Large",  
pd.np.where(df1['Local Channel Name'].str.contains(regex7),"Medium",  
pd.np.where(df1['Cust Type Name'].str.contains(regex8),"WS",  
pd.np.where(df1['Cust Type Name'].str.contains(regex9),"HFS Others",
pd.np.where(df1['Cust Type Name'].str.contains(regex10),"SUBED", "Small")))))))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df['New_Column'] = np.where(df['Local Channel Name'].str.contains('HFS'), 'MM', np.where(df['Local Channel Name'].str.contains('MR'), 'MR', 'Small'))
```